# Talend (if, else) in tJavaRow module

Tags: java, conditional-statements, talend

I'm trying to add informations in one column by using tJavaRow module and using conditional expression. The target here is simple. If "Fonction_libelle" column containt "DIRECTEUR" information, add in "Directeur_Oui_Non" column "Oui" else add "Non". I tried this :

```
if (input_row.Fonction_libelle == "DIRECTEUR") { output_row.Directeur_Oui_Non = "Oui";} else {output_row.Directeur_Oui_Non = "Non";}
```

The output of this is i've got "Non" everywhere but there are some "DIRECTEUR" in "Fonction_libelle" column. Of course there is something wrong but i'm not able to see what...

[image]

Any help would be very appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with .equals() instead of ==

```
if ("DIRECTEUR".equals(input_row.Fonction_libelle)) {
 output_row.Directeur_Oui_Non = "Oui";}
 else {output_row.Directeur_Oui_Non = "Non";}
```

"==" is not recommended to compare strings

Comment: Perfect ! I'll validate your response soon :)